# Why is there no << in the Haskell standard library?

Tags: haskell, monads

The `Monad` class defines a `>>` method, which sequences two monadic actions:

```
>> :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b
```

The binding operator `>>=` has a flipped-argument equivalent, `=<<`; as do the monadic function composition ('fish') operators `>=>` and `<=<`. There doesn't seem to be a `<<`, though (after a few minutes of Hoogling). Why is this?

Edit: I know it's not a big deal. I just like the way certain lines of code look with the left-pointing operators. `x <- doSomething =<< doSomethingElse` just looks nicer, with the arrows all going the same way, than `x <- doSomethingElse >>= doSomething`.

Comment: Nobody made a case for it.

Comment: They didn't think of it when they made `=<<` and `<=<`? I dunno why it's bothering me, it just seems like an oversight.

Comment: Uh, do those examples both do the same thing?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Don't they?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Yes, they do. poorsod, Apparently they didn't think of it, or deemed it unconvincing.

Comment: OK, well one binds `x` to `doSomething`, while the other binds it to `doSomethingElse`. I thought that would make them behave differently, but perhaps I'm mistaken...

Comment: @DanielFischer - thanks for your time. I had a feeling it had simply been forgotten, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't some important and deep reason, as there often is with confusing things in Haskell.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid They both bind `x` to the object inside the monad `doSomething >>= doSomethingElse`, which is the same as `doSomethingElse =<< doSomething`. The RHS is evaluated fully before the assignment is made, just like in an imperative language.

Comment: Oh, right. So I've got my operator precedences wrong. Sorry about that...

Comment: @poorsod Well, there is some reason why `<=<` and `=<<` are in while `<<` didn't make it (either past the decision-making or even to the decision-making). Your example illustrates that, `x <- amb =<< ma` is more or less natural, `x <- mb << ma` not, you'd write the `ma` on the line above, and simply `x <- mb`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Occasionally I like to use the right-to-left versions outside of a `do` block, because function composition using `.` is read from right-to-left. It makes the analogy between `<=<` and `.` visually clear.

Comment: @poorsod Yes, that is a case where `<<` would be useful. But it's one case less than for `<=<` and `=<<`, therefore _some_ reason. It's not a compelling reason.

Comment: @DanielFischer I understand. Thanks for the interesting points.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge there is no good reason.  Note, that your `Monad` should also be an instance of `Applicative`, so you can use `<*` and `*>` instead as your sequencing tools.

Comment: But note that although `*>` is equivalent to `>>`, `a <* b` is NOT equivalent to `b *> a`.

Comment: @dave4420 that is a good point.  `flip (*>)` and `flip (>>)` are always an option though.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an alternative answer, as a similar question was recently asked and marked a duplicate.    It turns out that **it's not at all clear what the definition of `(<<)` should be!**  While this issue was alluded to in the comments on the older answer, I don't think it was made entirely clear that there's a significant problem here.

Obviously, the two reasonable possibilities for a definition are:

```
(<<) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m a
p << q = do {x <- p; q; return x}   -- definition #1
p << q = do {q; p}                  -- definition #2
```

By analogy with the applicative operators `(<*)` and `(*>)`, it's clear that the new `(<<)` operator should preserve the ordering of side effects from left to right and only have the effect of switching which action's return value is used, so definition #1 is obviously the correct one.  This has the desirable property that `<<` and `<*` will be synonymous for (well-behaved) monads, just as `>>` and `*>` are synonymous, so no surprises.

Of course, by analogy with `=<<` and `>>=`, it's clear that flipping the direction of the greater than signs should have the effect of flipping the arguments, so definiton #2 is obviously the correct one.  This has the desirable property that a pipeline of monadic operations:

```
u >>= v >>= w >> x >>= y
```

can be reversed by flipping the operators:

```
y =<< x << w =<< v =<< u
```

This also preserves the identities for the Kleisli operators:

```
(f >=> g) x  ===  f x >>= g
(f <=< g) x  ===  f =<< g x
```

which certainly *look* like they ought to hold.

Anyway, I don't know if this was the original reason `(<<)` was left out.  (Probably not, as the decision would have predated the introduction of applicative operators, so people would have assumed "definition #2" as the only possibility), but I'm pretty sure it would be a sticking point now, as the different behavior of `(<<)` and `(<*)` would be quite unexpected given the close association people expect between applicative and monad operations.

Comment: `(<*)` and `(*>)` are not variants of each other that preserve the ordering of effects; they are variants of `(<*>)` that do less combining of the contained values. So the correct analogy in the first paragraph would be that, just like `(>>)` is a variant of `(>>=)` that does less combining of the contained values, `(<<)` should be a variant of `(=<<)` that does less combining of the contained values. (There is no uber combinator `>>=<<` or whatever of which both `(>>)` and `(<<)` should be variants.) This brings the two arguments into harmony, firmly supporting the side of definition #1.

Comment: @K.A. Buhr thank you for answering this question. I would highly disagree with @DanielWagner, #1 definition would be really confusing and useless, since `<*`  could really be used in it's place. On the other hand definition #2 could actually be used for writing clear code, namely in composition with `<=<` and `=<<`.

Comment: @lehins Yep, I checked and double-checked and still got it wrong: my comment should say "...firmly supporting the side of definition #2.".