# The missing << operator

Tags: haskell, monads

Today I want to compile the list of different, but related operators available today in `base` and ask why this one is missing: `(<<)`? I apologize for the long preamble, but it is a question about a pretty fundamental part of Haskell which I can't find an answer to.

**Edit** @Bob Dalgleish thank you for pointing this out. There seems to be already a question like this one: [Why is there no << in the Haskell standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176667/why-is-there-no-in-the-haskell-standard-library) That's great, since that means I am not the only one wondering about this. Nevertheless, the accepted answer to that question was "no good reason", which IMHO is not satisfactory. Also that same answer notes that `<*` can be used instead, which is incorrect since they have different semantics. Read below for more details.

I am not gonna go into details on what exactly each operator does, and what it can be used for, but I'll list their type signatures and infix precedence as well as associativity:

## Application

### Function

- Application: `($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b` (`infixr 0`)
- Flipped application: `(&) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b` (`infixl 1`)

### Functor

- fmap: `(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` (`infixl 4`)
- Flipped fmap: `(<&>) :: Functor f => f a -> (a -> b) -> f b` (`infixl 1`)
- Discard left: `($>) :: Functor f => f a -> b -> f b` (`infixl 4`)
- Discard right: `(<$) :: Functor f => a -> f b -> f a` (`infixl 4`)

### Aplicative

- App: `(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` (`infixl 4 <*>`)
- Flipped App: `(<**>) :: Applicative f => f a -> f (a -> b) -> f b` (`infixl 4 <**>`)
- Discard left: `(*>) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f b` (`infixl 4 *>`)
- Discard right: `(<*) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f a` (`infixl 4 <*`)

### Monad

- Bind: `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b` (`infixl 1 >>=`)
- Flipped bind: `(=<<) :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b` (`infixr 1 =<<`)
- Discard left: `(>>) :: Monad m => m a -> m b -> m b` (`infixl 1 >>`)
- **Discard right is missing!**

I'd expect to have a definition along those lines:

```hs
-- | Just like `(>>)`, but with arguments flipped.
(<<) :: Monad m => m b -> m a -> m b
k << m = const k =<< m
infixr 1 <<
```

Which is equivalent to both either `(<<) = flip (>>)` or `k << m = (\_ -> k) =<< m`

Some might say: "Why do we need `<<` if we can use `<*`?". But these two operators are very different:

- They might be using different implementation, after all `>>` and `<*` are functions of two different classes with default implementations and can be overridden.
- Because of difference in precedence we often can't use `<*` with `=<<` or `*>` with `>>=` without parenthesis:

  - `pure 5 >>= print >> pure 6` vs `(pure 5 >>= print) *> pure 6`
- For `Applicative`s information always flows from left to right, while for monads it can be reversed:

  - `print 5 *> print 7 *> print 6` == `print 5 <* print 7 <* print 6`
  - `print 5 >> print 7 >> print 6` /= `print 5 << print 7 << print 6`

## Composition:

We are very well familiar with function composition. It has also information flowing from right to left, and doesn't compose naturally with left-to-right flow, i.e. just looks a bit awkward. It's no big deal, but I wanted to mention it anyways.

- Compose: `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c` (`infixr 9 .`)

Here are two examples with order of execution of functions (not operators)

```hs
-- 4.         3.      2.            1.
λ> print 8 << print . succ =<< 6 <$ print 5
5
7
8
```

Note, that I'd need parenthesis if used `*>` instead of `>>`, otherwise it wouldn't compile.

```hs
--  1.               3.      2.       4
λ> print 5 $> 6 >>= print . succ >> print 8
5
7
8
```

## Consistency

Finally, all of the operators have there opposite directions counterparts. Some of them are listed above, but there a re also:
 * Kleisli: `(>=>)` vs `(<=<)`
 * Category: `(>>>)` vs `(<<<)`
 * Arrows: `(^>>)` vs `(<<^)` and `(>>^)` vs `(^<<)`

## So why don't we have `(<<)`?

- Is there some fundamental reason why it was excluded?
- Maybe no one really cares about this style of programming and people tend to just stick to the `do` notation?
- Maybe people find right-to-left flow information confusing. But that would surprise me, since function composition is like bread and butter in Haskell.
- It's hard to find any info on this topic, partially cause it's not easy to search special characters online, partially cause there are too many tutorials about monads :) Any link to such discussions would be appreciated.

For the benefit of those googling this in the future here is the question without the operator: Why don't we have the left monadic bind operator that discard the results of the right action?

Comment: I'm not sure how fundamental it can be if it's missing. Presumably, nobody has ever seen a need for it. Voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @chepner Not the operator or this question are fundamental. The part of Haskell that this question relates to is fundamental, namely the Monad! If you don't know the answer to the question don't answer. I did not express my opinion, but listed all of the facts that I could find on this topic.

Comment: @BobDalgleish I can't believe that "No good reason" is the best that Haskell community and stackoverflow can do. With regards to the solution proposed in the duplicate question, I go into the details why it is not the same to use `<*` vs `<<`

Comment: This does seem like an odd oversight, but then again, there are a lot of odd oversights in prelude. Some of them are just mistakes, others probably "seemed like a good idea at the time", and others have an actual historical reason for existing. I'd be interested to see which category this falls into, though it's probably just a mistake.

Comment: That is precisely the point for this question. If it is indeed an oversight, I will be happy to submit a PR to `base` with this operator, but I want to get some discussion from the community first.

Comment: The community you want to have this discussion with is *precisely* the people who will approve or reject such a pull request. They'll tell you "Yes, that was an oversight, thanks for the patch" or "No thanks, because ...". Nothing we say or speculate about here is going to affect that.

Comment: @chepner Community is the people who use Haskell, not the ones who maintain ghc. The latter do have the ultimate decision, but it will be driven by the community. Is it not the same in bash scripting? :D

Comment: "I don't like the answer" doesn't mean the answer is incorrect...

Comment: @DanielWagner, I disagree with the answer and believe that it is incorrect to think of `<*` as `<<`. The fact that you like the answer, doesn't make it correct either. But thank you for the discussion. That is exactly what I was trying to get out of everyone.

Comment: @lehins Why do you believe this is incorrect? All `Monad` instances are required by the type system to have an `Applicative` instance. This instance is also supposed to satisfy the law `(*>) = (>>)` as [stated in the documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Applicative), therefore `(<*) = flip (*>) = flip (>>)` which is the same as the proposed `(<<)`. What is the difference?

Comment: @David Note that `(<*)` is not `flip (*>)`; rather, `flip (<*)` is what lehins would like to have as `(<<)`. See [K. A. Buhr's answer to the target question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55620742/2751851) for extra commentary on that point.

Comment: Thanks @duplode 
@David If you look closely you will see that `(<*)` is not the same as `flip (>>)`. Not only because of precedence, but also because of the order of evaluation. There is a law clearly stating that `(*>)` should be equal to `(>>)`, nothing says that there is such a law for the the right to left operator, so there is no such constraint for `(<*)` to be equivalent to `(<<)`. Moreover, `m >> k = m >>= (\_ -> k)`, so it only makes sense to have `k << m = (\_ -> k) =<< m`, or simply `(<<) = flip (>>)`, Applicative has nothing to do with the latter definitions, in my opinion.

Comment: (Correcting a silly typo: in my comment above, I meant to write "[...] rather, `flip (*>)` is what lehins [...]".)

Comment: Ah, right. I forgot to take that aspect into account.

Comment: This is a good proposal, I see no reason not to add this operator.